# ArrayList Constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
       elementData = c.toArray();
       size = elementData.length;

       if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
             elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
}
```

I did not understand that "if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)" statement and why it is required. This is the implementation for ArrayList constructor. Can someone please explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`Collection.toArray()` might return an `Object` array, or it might return some other array type that has been cast to an `Object` array. The code you quote is making sure that its data array is actually an `Object` array, so it is able to receive any `Object`.